# Merge Two WordPress User Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wp_users MySQL table and a wp_users2 MySQL table.
wp_users2 has more users than wp_users.

I would like to take all the users in wp_users2 which are not already in wp_users, and copy them over to wp_users.

I don't want to delete any existing wp_users users, only add missing users to the wp_users table. The existing records should not be modified or updated.

How can this be achieved in MySQL?

Thank you!

Comment: Put the two tables in order to see its structure

Comment: Sure. Standard WP_Users tables:

http://pastebin.com/KJQMHC6L

So both tables are similar, but wp_users2 has more entries then wp_users. I want to copy all the missing entries to wp_users. If the entries already exist in wp_users, they should just be skipped and NOT altered/updated.

I'm looking at a LEFT OUTER JOIN but I haven't been successful yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your two tables have the same structure (and the same columns' order) and I suppose you want to copy every record (including the id) from wp_users2 to wp_users if the record is not already in wp_users you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_users 
VALUES (
    SELECT * FROM wp_users2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_users)
);
```

If the structure is not the same you will have to change the insert to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_users column1,column2,column3
VALUES (
    SELECT firstColumn, secondColumn, thridColumn 
    FROM wp_users2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_users)
);
```